# Working with Dynamic Types

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

I am using entity model with a SQL DB, and I have a set of about 30 lookup tables which are in the same 3 column format, **ID**, **Text**, **IsActive**. But rather than create 30 forms I would like to create one form and depending on the string name of a type given, then populate a gridview and allow ability to **Insert**, **Update** or **Delete** records of that type.

I have tried

```
string objectType = "Namespace.Models.BenefitType";
object o = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(objectType);
Type t = o.GetType();
```

but I can not access the type, I get a message about it being a type of System.Type not BenefitType.

Can someone advise me on how I can cast a type that is unknown until called dynamically.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go with an interface and then a generic type (or generic methods) rather than doing things genuinely dynamically, if you possibly can. If your autogenerated code uses partial classes, this is really easy to do - just write the interface around what you've currently got, and then add a new file with:

```
public partial class BenefitType : ICommonType {}
public partial class OtherType : ICommonType{} 
// etc
```

Then you can write:

```
public class LookupForm<T> : Form where T : ICommonType, new()
```

and you're away. The downside is that the designer isn't terribly happy with generic types.

If you need to *use* this based only on the type name, you can still do that:

```
string objectType = "Namespace.Models.BenefitType";
Type type = Type.GetType(objectType);
Type formType = typeof(LookupForm<>).MakeGenericType(type);
Form form = (Form) Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
```

You *might* want to create an abstract nongeneric form between `LookupForm<T>` and `Form` which you can use in a strongly-typed way, but which doesn't have anything to do with `T`. It depends on exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your options are limited.  The framework needs to be able to know more about type information than just a string name *at compile time* to be able to use them easily.  That means doing something like a switch statement on your type string, which isn't very nice, or making sure all your dynamic types implement some common interface you can cast to (much better).

In C# 4.0, you will be able to use the `dynamic` keyword to resolve these calls at runtime.